# Is there a reason IC in the DIP package seem to have a very high propagation delay and so a very limited admitted frequency?

Tags: frequency, delay, packages, propagation

I scrolled through Mouser and I noticed that when you search for ICs with very low propagation delays there are only IC avaible in packages quite hard to use for an hobbyst/noob like me with very limited tools.

Comment: To keep lead inductance as low as possible and hence significantly reduce reactive impedances at circa 1 GHz (and above) to about 50% compared to DIP devices.

Comment: You may choose **DIP** package because prototypes are to be built on breadboards/protoboards. Not very compatible with high-speed circuits.

Comment: Surface mount packages that still have physical leads are actually much faster and easier to work with by hand than DIP's.   It's only when you get into QFN, DFN, BGA, etc that things get hard.  The key to surface mount is realizing that you don't solder the pins individually, rather you let flux and surface tension do the detail work.  If you get a bridge, add flux, try to drag the solder off and if that doesn't work use fine desoldering braid to wick out the excess.  And removing SMD with a cheap hot air tool far, far easier than removing DIP.

Answer (score 3):

Partially because large packages mean large package parasitics, that simply cannot be overcome without shrinking the package.

Probably more so because the world has pretty much gone over to surface mount.  There's really not that much to recommend through-hole parts to a manufacturer, unless it's the cheapest simplest possible thing.